# XGBoost Best Iteration

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, regression, xgboost

I am running a regression using the XGBoost Algorithm as,

```
clf = XGBRegressor(eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)],
                       early_stopping_rounds = 10, 
                       n_estimators = 10,                    
                       verbose = 50)

clf.fit(X_train, y_train, verbose=False)
print("Best Iteration: {}".format(clf.booster().best_iteration))
```

It correctly trains itself, but the print function raises the following error,

```
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

How can I get the number of the **best** **iteration** of the model?

Furthermore, how can I print the **training** **error** of **each** **round**?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For your TypeError: use [get_booster()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.get_booster) instead of booster()

```
print("Best Iteration: {}".format(clf.get_booster().best_iteration))
```

To use the number of the best iteration when you **predict**, you have a parameter called `ntree_limit` which specify the number of boosters to use. And the value generated from the training process is `best_ntree_limit` which can be called after training your model in the following matter: `clg.get_booster().best_ntree_limit`. More specifically when you predict, use:

```
best_iteration = clg.get_booster().best_ntree_limit
predict(data, ntree_limit=best_iteration)
```

You can print your training and evaluating process if you specify those parameters in the [.fit()](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit) command

```
clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
        eval_set = [(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)],
        eval_metric = 'rmse',
        early_stopping_rounds = 10, verbose=True)
```

**NOTE:** early_stopping_rounds parameter should be in the `.fit()` command not in the `XGBRegressor()` instantiation.

**Another NOTE:** `verbose = 50` in `XGBRegressor()` is redundant. The `verbose` variable should be in your `.fit()` function and is True or False. For what the verbose=True do, [read here](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor.fit) under the verbose section. It is directly affects your 3rd question.

Answer (score 3):

Your error is that the `booster` attribute of [`XGBRegressor`](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBRegressor) is a string that specifies the kind of booster to use, not the actual booster instance. From the docs:

> **booster: string**
>   Specify which booster to use: gbtree, gblinear or dart.

In order to get the actual booster, you can call `get_booster()` instead:

```
>>> clf.booster
'gbtree'
>>> clf.get_booster()
<xgboost.core.Booster object at 0x118c40cf8>
>>> clf.get_booster().best_iteration
9
>>> print("Best Iteration: {}".format(clf.get_booster().best_iteration))
Best Iteration: 9
```

I'm not sure about the second half of your question, namely:

> Furthermore, how can I print the **training error** of ** each round**?

but hopefully you're unblocked!