# xgboost.train bst_score returns training error, not validation error?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using the XGBoost python API and am training my model using the code below.

```
    num_round =100
    param = {  'alpha': 0.28342488159238677, 'eta' : 0.43347953113507033, 'max_depth': 2, 'min_child_weight' :8.774621448662675,
            'objective':'binary:logistic'}
    dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, label=y)
    dval = xgb.DMatrix(val, label=val_y)

    evallist = [(dval, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')]
    bst = xgb.train(param, dtrain, evals= evallist, early_stopping_rounds=100, evals_result = eval_dict )
```

I'm concerned that when I print(bst.best_score) it returns the best training score (which also agrees with bst.best_iteration), but often times this isn't the iteration with the best validation score. Shouldn't I be mostly interested in the validation score?  I don't want an iteration that has crazy good (overfitted) training error, I want the one the performs the best on the validation set?

I am using best_ntree_limit to make predictions (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51955256/xgboost-best-iteration)), but does this mean I am using the model with lowest training error to make my prediction? I am guessing I can change this somewhere to use validation error for the "best" metrics, but I'm confused because I never see anyone do it in examples.

Comment: question has been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53483648/is-the-xgboost-documentation-wrong-early-stopping-rounds-and-best-and-last-it

Comment: Thanks, this shows how to make it use validation error instead (thanks) but doesn't show which approach is correct. In the API documentation they are using evallist = [(dtest, 'eval'), (dtrain, 'train')], which means it is using train error. But I find examples that use validation error. I'm trying to understand which is the 'correct' approach (and under what circumstances). I've tested with both, and in some cases optimizing toward validation error gives worse performance (ROC, F1, accuracy). Is there a best practice regarding using validation or train error for early stopping/best model?

Comment: you always use validation error to monitor your model. Using the train error will most of the time result in overfitting or underfitting. For the validation error, it depends on the split you do and it depends of the eval data set. This is why you try to remove the std by using KFold. This also why you always fix the seed to get reproducible tests and not seed based improvements ( the seed does have a HUGE importance on edgy models)

Comment: As Alexis already said, one should always do early stopping based on a validation set. Early stopping on the training set does not make sense as one can always reduce the error to zero by memorising the training instances, as long as the model is complex enough, but some model will not generalize.
As for how to achieve it- put the set that you want to use in early stopping criteria last in the `evals` list.